# Launching a Java JPanel from a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, jpanel

I am a not very experienced when it comes to Java Spring but what I was hoping to achieve was to launch a JPanel after a specific controller method is invoked after a user submits a form. Unfortunately, I am getting an error when I try to launch my JPanel in the Spring application. I've tried to find examples of people using JPanel in combination with Spring and I could not find anything, so I am inclined to believe that the use of JPanel in combination with Spring is not possible.

The expected behavior is that when the form is submitted, some relevant information relating to the submitted form pops up in a newly Created JPanel.

Also, note that I tried to run the GUI generating code in a separate class and it worked perfectly fine. It was only when I tried running the code inside of the Spring application when problems arrived.

My Spring controller Class (Relevant method is createForm())

```
package com.datavisulizer.datavisulizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.SimpleBindings;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import org.objectweb.asm.*;

@Controller
public class indexController {


    @GetMapping("/create")
    public String createPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("codeForm", new codeForm());
        return "create";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String createForm(codeForm cf) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(cf.getCodeText());
        ArrayList<String[]> CL = codeParser(cf.getCodeText());
        String name = classFinder(CL);
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("java");
        //GUI Code START
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add( new JLabel(" Outout" ), BorderLayout.NORTH );

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        TextAreaOutputStream taos = new TextAreaOutputStream( ta, 60 );
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( taos );
        System.setOut( ps );
        System.setErr( ps );


        frame.add( new JScrollPane( ta )  );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        //GUI CODE END

        if (engine == null) {
            System.err.println("Engine error (unknown engine)!");
        } else {
            try{
                engine.put(ScriptEngine.FILENAME, name);
                engine.eval(cf.getCodeText());
                cf.setCodeTextOutput("Java code Succefully compiled...");
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                cf.setCodeTextOutput("Java code has an error");

            }
            
        }
        return "create";
    }

    private String classFinder(ArrayList<String[]> CL){
        String name = "_No_Name";
        if(CL.size()<1 || CL.get(0).length<2) return name;
        return CL.get(0)[CL.get(0).length-1] + ".java";
    }

    private ArrayList codeParser(String code){
        ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = "";
        for(int c = 0; c<code.length()-1; c++){
            if(code.substring(c, c+1).compareTo("{")==0 || code.substring(c, c+1).compareTo("}")==0){
                lineList.add(line);
                line = "";
            }
            else{
                line+=code.substring(c, c+1);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<String[]> codeList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for(String s : lineList){codeList.add(s.split(" "));}
        System.out.println("Testing code array list");
        for(String[] s : codeList){for(String c : s){System.out.println(c);}}
        return codeList;
    }

}
```

Console Logs

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.awt.HeadlessException] with root cause

java.awt.HeadlessException: null
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:166) ~[na:na]
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:553) ~[na:na]
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:428) ~[na:na]
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:393) ~[na:na]
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180) ~[na:na]
        at com.datavisulizer.datavisulizer.indexController.createForm(indexController.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] 
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]       
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html)
you can only do this

> Create lightweight components such as Canvas, Panel, and Swing components, except the top levels

you can enable headless mode using

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

or

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to solve the problem. In the console I am still getting this error: `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.awt.HeadlessException] with root cause`

Comment: remove your `JFrame` and don't make it visible, only use canvas and panel for few custom purpose alone, you are not suppose to create JFrame and make it visible

Comment: I looked a little more into enabling headless mode and it looks like there seems to be a specific process and or location where I need to enable this feature. So, my initial approach of just adding the above recommended line in my method might be incorrect.

Comment: the feature you are assuming does not exists, you can only create panel and canvas without making it visible, if you tell me what are you trying to achieve in swing, I can help

Comment: No problem! I can add more code if that helps too! The big picture is that I am trying to allow a user to submit some java code via a html form. That code is then processed, and any logging information is to be printed in a separate console that will pop up in the form of a JPanel.

Comment: Ideally, I would add the logging information (which I would be moving from my embedded terminal in my ide to the spring application) but there was far more documentation on moving the logs from the local terminal onto a separate JPanel which is why I went for that approach.

Comment: I would understand that you are trying to visualize the server logs in GUI, you can do this using Log4J and ChainSaw https://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/2.x/, sacrifice your current code and start investing time in this topic

Comment: I wanted to make sure that the solution given 100% did not work before I went on to create a new application and I am glad I did because I managed to make it work. The key is making sure that the code is the first thing to be ran in the main method. Thank you so much for your help!!!